# How to remove first two digits from a given 10 digit number and that number is convert to string using robot framework

Tags: robotframework-pythonremoteserver

How to remove first two digits from a given 10 digit number and that number is convert to string using robot framework

I want a number but first two digits should be removed from given 10 digit number
And also that number is converted to string.
And in output new number ( first two digits should be removed) should be displayed